# War deployment to Tomcat in Eclipse works, but not to stand alone Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a Spring based Maven built web app project in Eclipse that is deployed by Eclipse to a Tomcat server controlled by Eclipse. There I don't have any issues.

When I try to deploy it to a stand alone Tomcat server I get some pages working but also some nasty crashes.

I have tried to deploy them with the same `server.xml` `web.xml` `catalina.properties` `catalina.policy`and `context.xml` but the crashes persist.

I'm reluctant to change the actual Java code since that works when the project is launched from within Eclipse.

Please see stacktrace below:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to set property service for managed bean loginMgmtBean
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:615)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ChainAwareVariableResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.faces.expression.ELDelegatingVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ELDelegatingVariableResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver.resolveOriginal(DelegatingVariableResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.jsf.SpringBeanVariableResolver.resolveVariable(SpringBeanVariableResolver.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverChainWrapper.getValue(VariableResolverChainWrapper.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:260)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1083)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean userService
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ChainAwareVariableResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.faces.expression.ELDelegatingVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ELDelegatingVariableResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver.resolveOriginal(DelegatingVariableResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.jsf.SpringBeanVariableResolver.resolveVariable(SpringBeanVariableResolver.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverChainWrapper.getValue(VariableResolverChainWrapper.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.evaluate(BeanBuilder.java:591)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:606)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:114)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Class.getTypeName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: I have seen this error when you set a property in the bean but the class does not have a setter method for it...

Comment: you need to have jar in tomcat lib folder

Comment: @shreyanshjogi Could you be more elaborate in that?

Comment: spring dependencies should be available in classpath

Comment: @shreyanshjogi But isn't that handled by the packaged war file? It seems to include all the dependencies for the app.

Comment: yes but sometimes it conflicts with jar available in application and tomcat

Comment: @shreyanshjogi I did some investigations and it seems your suggestion was on the right track. Weirdly enough it crashes when I use non overridden methods inherited from `Object`. I removed those for a proof of concept and it works. Soi I assume the CP to java core is somehow faulty. You know a more sustainable way to fix this? The post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible that it is taking jar files from the tomcat server libraries.

Sorry.. not sufficient reps to put a comment so posting it here.